# How to query parquet data files from Azure Synapse when data may be structured and exceed 8000 bytes in length

Tags: t-sql, parquet, azure-synapse

I am having trouble reading, querying and creating external tables from Parquet files stored in Datalake Storage gen2 from Azure Synapse.

Specifically I see this error while trying to create an external table through the UI:

[image: UI external table creation]

"Error details
New external table
Previewing the file data failed. Details: Failed to execute query. Error: Column 'members' of type 'NVARCHAR' is not compatible with external data type 'JSON string. (underlying parquet nested/repeatable column must be read as VARCHAR or CHAR)'. File/External table name:  [DELETED] Total size of data scanned is 1 megabytes, total size of data moved is 0 megabytes, total size of data written is 0 megabytes.
. If the issue persists, contact support and provide the following id :"

My main hunch is that since a couple columns were originally JSON types, and some of the rows are quite long (up to 9000 characters right now, which could increase at any point in time during my ETL), this is some kind of conflict with some possible default limit's I have seen referenced in the documentation ([enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-data-types#minimize-row-length)). Data appears internally like the following example, please bear in mind sometimes this would be way longer

```
["100.001", "100.002", "100.003", "100.004", "100.005", "100.006", "100.023"]
```

If I try to manually create the external table (which has worked every other time I have tried following code similar to this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE example1(
    [id] bigint,
    [column1] nvarchar(4000),
    [column2] nvarchar(4000),
    [column3] datetime2(7)
    )
    WITH (
    LOCATION = 'location/**',
    DATA_SOURCE = [datasource],
    FILE_FORMAT = [SynapseParquetFormat]
    )
GO
```

the table is created with no error nor warnings but trying to make a very simple select

```
SELECT TOP (100) [id] bigint,
        [column1] nvarchar(4000),
        [column2] nvarchar(4000),
        [column3] datetime2(7)
 FROM [schema1].[example1]
```

The following error is shown:
"External table 'dbo' is not accessible because content of directory cannot be listed."

It can also show the equivalent:
"External table 'schema1' is not accessible because content of directory cannot be listed."

This error persists even when creating external table with the argument "max" as it appears in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

Summary: How to create external table from parquet files with fields exceeding 4000, 8000 bytes or even up to 2gb, which would be the maximum size according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Thank you all in advance

Comment: What is Azure Synapse has to do with SQL Server? Please do not tag spam.